# How to re-initiate a Pull Request in GitHub

Tags: github

I did a pull request to the master branch that failed as we had a problem with a Continuous Integration file that caused the failure. As the CI file was fixed, I like to re-initiate the pull request again.  Not sure how to do this.

Comment: If you've pushed a new commit to the branch the PR is coming from it should automatically update and rerun the build.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new commit and push it to the branch you created the PR on. Another solution can be to rebase one or more commits and force push them again.